# using sed to escape & characters

Tags: sed

I am trying to use gnu sed 4.7 to escape all `&` characters between two patterns of text. How would one go about this?

Here is my goal:

Before:

```
some&words& things& stuff###&this & area&is&what&should&change###more&text
```

After:

```
some&words& things& stuff###\&this \& area\&is\&what\&should\&change###more&text
```

This is on a Linux server with gnu sed 4.7 being initiated from a bash terminal.

```
sed -i -e "s/\(###\)\(.*\)\&\(.*\)\(###\)/\1\2\\\&\3\4/g" file.txt
```

The above line does not escape any `&` characters.

Comment: Would you also be OK with a Perl solution?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do this with pure regular expressions, either. It's easy if you split the string by ###, process the middle part with a simple regex, and then join again with ### to get you the result you want. Easy with Perl at least if you don't insist on sed...

Comment: I was hoping to allow this code to be executed with just base packages from a standard Linux install. But if there's no other way, a Perl solution would certainly be better than nothing.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "standard Linux install". Also, what Linux distribution doesn't package perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy with perl:

```
perl -i -pE 's{(###.*?###)}{$1 =~ s/&/\\&/gr}eg' file.txt
```

We use a nested substitution. The first pattern just grabs all chunks between `###` delimiters, then computes the replacement by running another substitution on the captured string, escaping all `&` characters.

Comment: Much thanks! I really need to take the time to get to know Perl. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This strikes me as a job for awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "###"} {gsub(/&/,"\\\\&",$2)} 1' file
```

Or to save the file inplace, like `sed -i` does:

```
gawk -i inplace 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "###"} {gsub(/&/,"\\\\&",$2)} 1' file
```

To address @melpomene's valid comment, the awk program is gets a little wordy:

```
gawk -i inplace '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = "###"} 
    {for (i=2; i<NF; i+=2) { gsub(/&/,"\\\\&",$i) }} 
    1
' file
```

Comment: That only works if you have exactly one pair of `###...###` per line.